# IS there a way to preserve tab spaces with postgres copy?

Tags: java, postgresql

I'm trying to copy some data from a Postgres database into a `ByteArrayOutputStream` object, so I'm using `copyManager` of the library `org.postgresql.copy.CopyManager`:

```
this.copyManager.copyOut("copy ("+sqlQuery+") TO STDOUT encoding 'WIN1252' " , bo)**
```

All it's working fine, except when I have some data with tab spaces like
`-  abcd`, when it does the copy, It replaces it by `\t`, so what I'm getting in the result is `-\tabcd`.

Could you help me please?

Comment: It doesnt *replace* anything. A tab IS `\t`. Tab-Spacing is just a way of displaying a tab. And `\t` is a way to write tabs in string-literals for example

Comment: How do you want to distinguish a tab used as a "tab space" from one separating the columns?

Comment: i hava no '\t' anymore, but now when i used CSV format, it has put "" everywere on my file, any ideas please ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the default `text` format, you want CSV:

```
COPY tab TO STDOUT (FORMAT 'csv', ENCODING 'WIN1252');
```

With psycopg2, use [`copy_expert`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert), thich allows you to specify the `COPY` SQL statement will all options you want.

To avoid escape characters (by default `"`), use a delimiter that does not occur in your data:

```
COPY tab TO STDOUT (FORMAT 'csv', ENCODING 'WIN1252', DELIMITER '|');
```

Comment: Thank you, i hava no '\t' anymore, but now when i used CSV format, it has put "" everywere on my file, any ideas please ?

Comment: That's how it should be. You can use a different delimiter as specified in my answer, but if you have exotic ideas of how the format should be, you best specify them in your question.